# Fetch users who have posted the last comment 3 days before eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Actually, I need to send the reminder emails to all my users in a time interval. So basically if a user has not posted any comment in last 3 days I need to send him the email.

I am using table structure:

**Users**

- id
- username
- email
- unsubscribed

**Comments**

- id
- user_id
- comment
- created_at

I have used the silly query for that

```
Comment::with(['user' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('unsubscribed', 0)->select('id', 'username', 'email');
    }])
->groupBy('user_id')
->whereDate('created_at', $thereDaysAgoDate)
->get(['user_id']);
```

This give me all the users who have posted comment on that particular date.

My issue is, `I only want the users who have posted a comment on that particular date but then not posted any comment after that date`.

I can do this by fetching all users from `comment` table and then compare date via PHP if else condition but I do not want to approach in this manner.

So is there any way to achieve this via eloquent only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `whereHas` and `whereDoesntHave` and also turn around the query to filter users by the condition met by their relationship

```
    $the_date = '2017-09-29';
    User::where('unsubscribed', 0)->whereHas('comments', function ($comments)  use ($the_date){
        return $comments->whereDate('created_at', '=', $the_date);
    })->whereDoesntHave('comments',  function($comments) use ($the_date){
        return $comments->whereDate('created_at', '>', $the_date);
    })->get();
```

> PS: I assume that you have `comments` relationship with User. This is tested on L5.5.*

Comment: How many queries generated by this code? If it only runs one query looks nice!

Comment: It should only run a single query using the `exists` and `not exists` sql conditionals with subqueries. You can inspect it yourself by changing the `->get()` to `->toSql()`

Comment: It's awesome buddy :) well its creating total 3 queries in term of subqueries that is not an issue its working accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $main_query =  Comment::with(['user' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('unsubscribed', 0)->select('id', 'username', 'email');
            }])
        ->groupBy('user_id');     

  $all_users = $main_query->whereDate('created_at', $thereDaysAgoDate)
        ->get(['user_id']);

  $users_who_have_posts_after = $main_query->
        ->whereDate('created_at','>', $thereDaysAgoDate)
        ->get(['user_id']);

  $users_without_post_after = $all_users->whereNotIn('user_id',$users_who_has_posts_after);
```

Maybe it isn't the nicest way but it only do 2 queries and a loop. 
I'm fetching all users who posted in desired date, then fetching users who still posting after our date and then compare the original users pool with the users who still active.

Comment: Good trick plus one for that :) But I think it can also be possible to the single query. Hope I can get any specific answer for this.